# How to apply class to first button of the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this html and I want to apply class to first button of the DIV.

```
<div class="button-container">
 <button class="save" />
 <button class="reset" />
</div>
```

I want to add class to the first button.

I want to use jQuery for this solution.

Comment: Do you want a CSS style that applies to the first button in the div? Then SleighBoy has the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the  [:first-child](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/firstChild)  selector

```
$("div.button-container button:first-child" ).addClass ( "yourclass" );
```

Answer (score 5):

You could look at this:
http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/firstChild

`$('div button:first-child').addClass(...)`

Answer (score 5):

```
div.button-container > button:first-child { font-weight: bold; }
```

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child

Answer (score 4):

You can add a second class like this.

```
<div class="button-container">
 <button class="save SecondClass" />
 <button class="reset" />
</div>
```